# Google analytics shows statics of different account

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I have two website accounts in google analytics. In one I have my old site A and new site B in another. Both of them are similar wordpress sites with different set of articles.I have placed analytics script on header files of both sites

When I check on the real time report of my old site, it shows some url's of my new site articles? There is no link or any sort of connection between these two sites

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the same tag in Google Tag Manager? Meaning...Do you have the same code in both sites? You will need the unique `GTM-` identifier...

Also make sure you set up different properties in Google backend.

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXX"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

Make sure `GTM-XXXX` is different on both.

Comment: Let me check once

Comment: If I have multiple sites, In a same google analytics login. Can I get a different tag manager ids?

Comment: You can create multiple Properties under a single Account.

Comment: Just to point out, the question does not actually mention Google Tag Manager (although the logic of the answer would equally apply to the GA snippet).

Comment: You're right, @Elike. Check this too: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en

Comment: You can create one Account and one property but 2 views (old,new) and then create a filter on New-view to only include the domain of your new website and same on old. You dont need 2 different accounts or properties. And yes you can have multiple GTM-id just create a container for each website